# Glass node not working?

Tags: node-editor, glass

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0r0UnaIK_Y&t=27s
on how to make an eyeball, I'm using blender 2.8 but the guy in the video is not, and even though my texture nodes looks exactly like his, my eye looks dried up and his is shiny. I'm not sure where the problem is, but I think it's the nodes. 
here are mine (top img) vs. his, hopefully someone can help me out.  thanks!

[image]

[image: tutorial guy's nodes]

Comment: Followed the tutorial myself, as it really caught my interest after seeing the result. So far the only difference i could find that made a big impact is that i had to turn the multiplier for the displacement down to 0.03, it looked better right away. Maybe a difference in the versions there. Too high displacement can make an object look rough as well. Also, did you try using an HDRI, with only the emission i didn't get the nice shine either.

Comment: Wondering, are the "Normals" of the eyeball in your scene maybe facing inside?
From the pictures i can't really figure much, it would help if you could attach your .blend file, thus allowing a more detailed analysis and eventually an answer.